# How can I get lost form data back?

Tags: forms

I had a form plugin installed. There was an issue with the plugin and although customers where competing the form, the form data was not being emailed.
We were able to get the form data back, but our host suggest we reset the plugin to get it to work, but after doing this the form data disappeared from the plugin.
I'm hoping the form data is still on the database, but I have no where to look for this - the plugin owner said that the data is there, just not in readable format.
would love to know if there are any ideas how to get this form data back.

Comment: How did you “reset” the plugin? You also said you already spoke to the plugin developer, so I’m not sure what anybody here could add.

Comment: this can't be answered without knowing which form plugin you're using, and the answer is different for every form plugin out there. **You need to ask this at their support or ask other people who use that plugin in one of their groups/communities, not here**. 3rd party plugin support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the plugin saves data. If it just processes the data (sending an email, for example), then the submitted data is lost.

If the plugin stores the data, it may be in the backup copies of your database, depending on when the backups were done relative to the form submittal. (You do have backup copies, right?)

The actual location of the data in the database (if that's where it was stored) is in the source code of the plugin. It might be in the 'options' table, perhaps in a record at the 'end' of that table.

Or it may just be lost forever.

Answer (score -1):

Your original issue — form data not being emailed — I doubt that the issue is with your form plugin. It’s far more likely to be that the standard email services provided by WordPress, PHP and your hosting provider are simply unreliable. In the early days of email they would have been fine, but nowadays email has gotten a lot more complex in its efforts to manage spam and spoofing. Today, for email to be delivered successfully (arriving in the recipient’s inbox and not flagged as spam) you need to implement the email [authentication protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_authentication), and neither WordPress nor PHP nor your hosting provider will do this for you.

So what we do is we **outsource that technical authentication stuff** to a transactional email service. The transactional service provider then provides an API to us, and we just need to install a plugin which will route outgoing mail to that API.

Comment: This read as a recommendation for a service, I've edited out the service recommendation and names so that it isn't interpreted as spam. Remember, answers should be self-contained. You can use links in your answer to support it, but your answer needs to be usable and understandable even if the links break, and you shouldn't recommend specific products and services